# Need to run wp_query on a separate php file for an ajax call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, templates

But it shows:

> Fatal error: Class 'WP_Query' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\word\wp-content\themes\word\templates\calendar-function.php
>   on line 67 .

Answer (score 0):

You need to include wp-load.php (it is present on root folder)
Like -

```
$abs_path= __FILE__;
$get_path=explode('wp-content',$abs_path);
$path=$get_path[0].'wp-load.php';
include($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the file calendar-function.php

```
$abs_path= __FILE__;
$get_path=explode('wp-content',$abs_path);
$path=$get_path[0].'wp-load.php';
include($path);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use WP AJAX api, never call the file in the theme directly.

Please refer to the codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)